# Why does Yarn modify package version in peer dependencies?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I was trying out Yarn V2 and put one of the dependencies in one workspace into the `peerDependency` section. But Yarn always modifies the version of the dependency to `*` no matter what version I wrote. Like this:

package.json (before)

```
{ "peerDependencies": { "packageA": "workspace:^0.0.1" } }
```

package.json (after)

```
{ "peerDependencies": { "packageA": "*" } }
```

where `packageA` is another local workspace managed by the monorepo. Doesn't `*` mean any version would satisfy? If this is a known Yarn feature, how could I specify a version in peer dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use another workspace dependency into your current dependency, you need to specify it inside `devDependencies` section like this

```
{ "devDependencies": { "packageA": "workspace:^0.0.1" } }
```